Intel GPU is not recognized
I have a 12600k with GPU and drivers are installed (i915), but they don't seem to be used. I'm trying to run Blender and have very poor performances.In /etc/modprobe.d there is a file to blacklist Intel microcode. I don't know whether that's related.

You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using; why make us guess. If you're using a LTS release there is kernel stack choice, with default set by install media so we can't know what you're using unless told that too (why product & not just release matters). Please also have your question contain all details & not rely on header; which may not be viewable when reading your actual question (which reads as a statement too)

thanks for the answer. It is actually working in fact. Just that this gpu isn't very powerfull.
